# Compairing 4 graph in one graph

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have 4 dataframe with value count of number of occurance per month.
I want to compare all 4 value counts in one graph, so i can see visual difference between every month on these four years.
Like below
[i like to have output like this image with years and month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02FH9.png)

```
newdf2018.Month.value_counts()
output
1     3451
2     3895
3     3408
4     3365
5     3833
6     3543
7     3333
8     3219
9     3447
10    2943
11    3296
12    2909

newdf2017.Month.value_counts()
1     2801
2     3048
3     3620
4     3014
5     3226
6     3962
7     3500
8     3707
9     3601
10    3349
11    3743
12    2002

newdf2016.Month.value_counts()
1     3201
2     2034
3     2405
4     3805
5     3308
6     3212
7     3049
8     3777
9     3275
10    3099
11    3775
12    2115

newdf2015.Month.value_counts()
1     2817
2     2604
3     2711
4     2817
5     2670
6     2507
7     3256
8     2195
9     3304
10    3238
11    2005
12    2008
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create dictionary of `DataFrame`s and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) together, then use `plot`:

```
dfs = {2015:newdf2015, 2016:newdf2016, 2017:newdf2017, 2018:newdf2018}

df = pd.concat({k:v['Month'].value_counts() for k, v in dfs.items()}, axis=1)

df.plot.bar()
```

Comment: I got below error
```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Comment: @Adil - oops, need `df = pd.concat({k:v['Month'].value_counts() for k, v in dfs.items()}, axis=1)` instaed `df = pd.concat({k:v['Month'].value_counts() for k, v in dfs}, axis=1)`